# Is there a way to flag a user with an offensive name?

Tags: discussion

I flagged the answer left in this case, but the answer has now been deleted and the user left behind. And  more generally is there a better way of doing this?

User in question is [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/105608/sarcastic-dickhead).

Comment: What's wrong with the name "User105608"?

Comment: @Valorum Originally the username was "Sarcastic dickhead".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's still pretty borderline around here :-)

Comment: I didn't know we had a policy against certain user names. I walked around with the moniker of a *serial killer* for half a year and no one said anything. If this really is a problem, shouldn't SE already have checks when selecting a stack name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If they have a post you can flag, flag it.**

If they have a deleted post and you have more than 10k rep, flag that deleted post. If they have a post which isn't deleted, you can flag that - even if it's going to be deleted. Custom mod flags will remain until handled by a mod; they won't be automatically cleared by post deletion like NAA/VLQ flags will.

**Otherwise, flag any post to explain the situation.**

That could be the question where an answer from the rudely-named user was posted, as @TheLethalCarrot suggested. Or it could be literally any post you want. All moderator flags go into the same queue, so it doesn't matter where you flag as long as you make clear what the issue is, e.g. by linking to the rudely-named user's profile. You could flag one of your own posts, one of a moderator's posts, a recently active post on the home page, post number 123456, ... whatever, it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to flag the answer and link to the user explaining that you believe they should be nuked or renamed. If the answer is deleted before you get a chance to flag it you can then flag the question the answer was on and link to the user again. If the initial post was a question you can just flag any other post you want really, it shouldn't matter too much. I tend to pick one of my own posts but I don't think it matters much.

Comment: And in this case, I've already flagged the answer requesting that the user be destroyed / username reset.

Comment: @Mithrandir Me too as a 10k plus user it makes sense to do so.

Comment: "*flags on posts are automatically marked as helpful once the post is deleted*" - not custom mod flags. VLQ or NAA flags will be automatically marked as helpful, but if you use a custom mod flag on a post which is then deleted, the flag remains.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Not always, I’ve had customs flags be automatically marked as helpful. I believe there are a few feature requests to change this behaviour.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot How do you know it was automatically?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Because it was handled immediately when the answer was flag nuked.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot If the answer was flag-nuked *by a mod*, then I think that happens. Because that counts as a mod handling the flag. If the answer was flag-nuked by the community, the flag will stick around for a mod to look at. (Do you have a link to any particular cases?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I got mixed up with something else I think, edited and rewritten to be clearer.